# How can I make my feet "quicker"?

Tags: soccer, speed, football

I want to work on how quick my feet are. I know a handful of exercises but I am looking for something new that I haven't tried before. I am looking for both in gym exercisers, to incorporate into my existing routine, and also would like some exercises that I can do with the ball at my feet.

Basically, I haven't played very competitively in a while so my feet have gotten "slower" (how disheartening to admit). Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I don't know any gym/lifting excercises.
I know many different variations of skip touches.

Comment: Hi! It would be a good idea to list the exercise you already know/do, so we can know what to suggest to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [speed ladder](http://www.speedladder.com/). You can even [make one out of duct tape](http://ironmakeover.blogspot.ca/2010/04/duck-tape-agility-ladder.html). There are a bunch of footwork exercises you can do on a speed ladder. They're really hard to describe in text, so [here's a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYJX0Wt6OdM) with some intro ladder drills.

Answer (score 1):

One simple thing that you can do is start jumping rope. It's good for overall conditioning, and you have to get your feet moving quickly and rhythmically to do it well. There are tons of variations, too, so if you get good at straight skipping, you can do double jumps, cross overs, etc.